# NLog 1.5 Common.Logging.NLog10 unable to instaciante NLoggerFactoryAdapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, nlog, common.logging

I'm trying to use NLog with common.logging for the first time. I implemented NLog in a test project and it all went ok, then tried to apply common.logging but i'm having some dificulties.

Common.logging configuration under App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="common">
            <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <common>
        <logging>
            <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog10">
                <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
                <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
            </factoryAdapter>
        </logging>
    </common>
</configuration>
```

The error i'm getting is in Common.Logging.LogManager line 317

```
private static ILoggerFactoryAdapter BuildLoggerFactoryAdapterFromLogSettings(LogSetting setting)
        {
...
adapter = (ILoggerFactoryAdapter)Activator.CreateInstance(setting.FactoryAdapterType, args);
...
}
```

While debugging i can see both configType and configFile args being passed.

My NLog.config is set to always copy in my vs.

The error i get is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Common.Logging.ConfigurationException' occurred in NLogTutorial1.exe

Additional information: Unable to create instance of type Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter. Possible explanation is lack of zero arg and single arg NameValueCollection constructors
```

Visual Studio 2008

Common.Logging version 2.1.1

NLog version 1.5

C# Framework 3.5

Console Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using Common.Logging.NLog20 solved the problem.
From this site http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.1.0/reference/html/ch01.html

Common.Logging.NLog20 -> is linked against NLog 2.0.0.2

Common.Logging.NLog10 -> is linked against NLog 1.0.0.505

So for NLog 1.5 NLog20 should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Following below steps should definitely solve all configuration and missing dll issues.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27825054/384554